# Can't post data with postman

Tags: asp.net-web-api, postman

I have created a simple Web API project and I am trying to **POST** Data with **PostMan** software, but something does not work...

My web api **controller's name** is *ValuesController*.

My Data is something like this:

```
public class Data
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

This is my Post method:

```
public void Post([FromBody]string value)
{
    db.Datas.Add(new Data { Value = value });
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

This is in PostMan:

When I click the send button and then go to visual studio, value parameter of Post method is null:

If I go on, the postman finishes his work quitely, without any errors and then
in my table null value is added:
[image: Postman]

What can be problem?

**Edit:**

When I modified my Post method so:

```
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]string value)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest("Bad request");

    db.Datas.Add(new Data { Value = value });
    db.SaveChanges();

    return Ok();
}
```

I got "bad request" message in postman

Comment: What is the reason of down vote?

Comment: I have to admit that, in postman, when I click the send button, Data I have edited isn't shown. As I guess There should be my data with ID column too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your method parameter from **string** to **Data** like below

```
public void Post(Data value)
{
    db.Datas.Add(new Data { Value = value });
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

this will work.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to post Json data {"value":"value"} from the body but your method required only string in formbody just "value" pass in body as simple string not json object

Answer (score 0):

[HttpPost]

```
    public async Task<ActionResult<PaymentDetail>> PostPaymentDetail(PaymentDetail paymentDetail)
    {
        _context.paymentDetails.Add(paymentDetail);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtAction("GetPaymentDetail", new { id = paymentDetail.PaymentDetailId }, paymentDetail);
    }
```

Comment: when is post data trough postmen data inserted  in null format